# How to retreive all data from datasnapshot AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all the data about receta from my firebase real time database (Link to my firebase recetas image)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89Ds.jpg)
When I get the data from it using the code below, I get all the data but description and origin that is set to null

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    recetasReference = database.getReference().child("recetas");
    recetasReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Receta new_receta = ds.getValue(Receta.class);
                recetas.add(new_receta);

            }
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al mostrar", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

I tried debuggin, ds has the descripcion and origen correctly but i do not why they are set to null when creating the receta.
[ds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq1zG.jpg)
[receta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDnF5.jpg)
Any Idea?
Sorry if i made any mistake on the post, it is my first one.

Receta class:

```
public class Receta {

    private String name;
    private String autor;
    private String desc;
    private String origin;
    private String tiempoPrep;
    private String filepath;

public Receta(String user, String nombre, String 
            descripcion, String origen, String tiempo
            , String filepath) {
    this.autor = user;
    this.name = nombre;
    this.desc = descripcion;
    this.origin = origen;
    this.tiempoPrep = tiempo;
    this.filepath = filepath;
}
public Receta(String user, String nombre, String 
          descripcion, String origen, String tiempo) {
    this.autor = user;
    this.name = nombre;
    this.desc = descripcion;
    this.origin = origen;
    this.tiempoPrep = tiempo;
}

public Receta(){}

public String getNombre() {
    return name;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.name = nombre;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
}

public void setOrigin(String origen) {
    this.origin = origen;
}

public String getTiempoPrep() {
    return tiempoPrep;
}

public void setTiempoPrep(String tiempoPrep) {
    this.tiempoPrep = tiempoPrep;
}

public String getFilepath() {
    return filepath;
}

public void setFilepath(String filepath) {
    this.filepath = filepath;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model class `receta` property name(descripcion instead of desc and origen instead of origin)  should be identical to the key name in the Firebase database.

Your data class should look like these instead, having different names refering to the same variable is confusing.

```
public class Receta {
private String name;
private String autor;
private String descripcion;
private String origen;
private String tiempoPrep;
private String filepath;

public Receta(String name, String autor, String descripcion, String origen,
  String tiempoPrep, String filepath) {
this.name = name;
this.autor = autor;
this.descripcion = descripcion;
this.origen = origen;
this.tiempoPrep = tiempoPrep;
this.filepath = filepath;
}

public Receta(String name, String autor, String descripcion, String origen,
  String tiempoPrep) {
this.name = name;
this.autor = autor;
this.descripcion = descripcion;
this.origen = origen;
this.tiempoPrep = tiempoPrep;
}

public Receta() {
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAutor() {
return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
this.autor = autor;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getOrigen() {
return origen;
}

public void setOrigen(String origen) {
this.origen = origen;
}

public String getTiempoPrep() {
return tiempoPrep;
}

public void setTiempoPrep(String tiempoPrep) {
this.tiempoPrep = tiempoPrep;
}

public String getFilepath() {
return filepath;
}

public void setFilepath(String filepath) {
this.filepath = filepath;
}
}
```

Comment: The names where the same, descripcion and origen, i changed them to desc and origin to try with different names to the ones un firebase. I'll put the back as they where

Comment: make sure they are written the same way. please upload your model class Receta

Comment: I have added the Receta class

Comment: check out the data class. If on windows use shortcut `Alt+Insert` then choose generate either constructor or getters, setters. You'll avoid typos and is faster.

Comment: I correct the spelling mistake from origin to origen. Try now.

Comment: Don't know why it worked, but putting name does not show the name, i used the descripcion and origin you gave me and change name as it was (back to nombre)

Comment: Listen carefully, the key on the firebase must be the same as your variables. If you have nombre in Firebase, your class should have nombre. Because the firebase will look for exact match to initialize your class variable. If variable's name are different, Firebase can't map it like it doesn't recognize it. Understood?